# fcm - Find cause of error in sending a notification from firebase console

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

Sometimes when I try to send a notification from firebase console, I get a error message on top right: "Error sending message" It shows info icon next to the snackbar style error message but clicking on it does not give me any information. I want to know the cause of error. Last time I got the error due to unstable network connection but this time I have working stable internet but still I keep getting error.

Comment: Kindly be more clear, where does "Error sending message" appears? on you phone or firebase console?.

Comment: on firebase console

Comment: try to use this demo to see where's the problem 
http://demo.androidhive.info/firebase/notifications/